# Why the title 'Unforgiven' in the movie Unforgiven?

Tags: analysis, title, unforgiven

I just watched the 1992 film [*Unforgiven*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105695/) and I liked it a lot. But how does the title of this movie relate to its story?

Comment: Because it would be silly to give the title *Unforgiven* to the movie *When Harry Met Sally*.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a good question, and sent me digging.

I found a [terrific essay on the film](http://www.artsrn.ualberta.ca/william_beard/Unforgiven.htm) written by William Beard, and here is an excerpt that pertains to your question:

> That he should get away with killing while Ned dies horribly for not
>   killing creates the moral abyss into which Munny plunges in forsaking
>   his “good” self and embracing again his “bad” one. Here lies a way to
>   an interpretation of the film’s cryptic title. Munny’s wife Claudia,
>   in attempting his regeneration, in pulling him out of the maelstrom of
>   nihilistic compulsive violence and drunken self-obliteration into a
>   world of principle and language and family and human self-recognition,
>   forgives him. The act of forgiveness produces the (feminine)
>   redemptive result of self-forgiveness. In addressing at last the
>   buried consciousness of horror and guilt, the fiery cycle of
>   repression and violence whose first victim is the perpetrator is
>   broken, and the functional person William Munny (the “good”) is
>   dredged up into view.
>
> Once established in the social world of human relationships, gainful
>   occupation, the code of civility and “decency,” Munny is happier than
>   before. Even after the death of his wife, and despite the rather naive
>   and rudimentary nature of the precepts upon which he leans, he
>   continues forthrightly in the same path. The process which pushes him
>   back off that path begins with a condition of economic hardship and
>   the unfulfilling nature of his labour. Pig-farming is dirty,
>   frustrating, humiliating, and profitless. The temptation to move into
>   another form of paid work—killing for hire—is very strong, when that
>   work suffers none of the drawbacks just enumerated. In drawing Ned
>   Logan into the business, Munny wishes not only to provide himself with
>   a dependable co-worker, but to give himself a degree of orientation in
>   this strange endeavour. Ned, like Munny (and like the Eastwood persona
>   too), is a former hellraiser, now a respectable freeholding family
>   man.
>
> As the film proceeds Ned develops into Munny’s anchor to the world,
>   his reassurance that he has forsaken the old ways (which Ned also
>   witnessed), and his guarantee that his actions have some foothold in a
>   worthwhile life-pattern, in decency and fellow-feeling. But Munny
>   makes the mistake first of returning to killing (however different his
>   motives this time) and second of pulling Ned with him. When this
>   happens the results are different from what was anticipated (this too
>   is morally instructive). It is Ned who is punished for the
>   transgression, a transgression he did not truly commit; Munny does
>   everything and goes free, and gets paid to boot. It is not just that
>   any notion of a higher system of justice and moral equilibrium is
>   derisorily contradicted by this development. The death of Ned is also
>   Munny’s personal loss of his “good” self, his loss of Claudia’s
>   forgiveness and his own self-forgiveness. **When he walks into
>   Greely’s to kill Skinny and Little Bill he is a creature who has lost
>   salvation, a damned soul, “unforgiven.”**

If that was too much to take in, in a nutshell Munny had been forgiven by his wife, society and, most importantly, by himself - but the lure of his old ways are too tempting and he regresses into the violent world he had left behind, ultimately destroying the last vestiges of his 'good' self through the death of Ned. Ultimately he realizes what he is, what he has always been; unforgiven.

Comment: although this time though he is avenging his friend ned doesn't he?

Comment: Heavy stuff there!

Comment: @Dredd walking into the Saloon he's avenging Ned, but Ned wouldn't have need avenging if he hadn't dragged him along in the first place!

Answer (score 7):

To me, forgiveness is a running theme under all the major characters. The women refuse to forgive the cowboys, even after Bill fines them. Bill refuses to forgive English Bob for his past. The kid immediately seeks forgiveness when he kills the cowboy.

Comment: Now that you mention it, just about everyone in the movie is unforgiven for something. This answer deserves a lot more love. :)

Comment: The biggest one of all is that Will doesn’t forgive himself.

Answer (score 2):

"forgiveness is a running theme under all the major characters" I agree. Women refuse to forgive the innocent cowboy even after he showed sincere remorse, perhaps because what they knew they already did (hire assassins). Most importantly, Munny never forgave himself over what he had done in the past, felt sure he was going to hell. And he certainly will never forgive himself for getting Ned killed. As he says: "Ned didn't kill anyone."

Answer (score 1):

Even from the start of the film, the first taste we see is Quick Mike not forgiving Delilah for hurting his pride.  She gets slashed. There’s no forgiveness from Little Bill toward the Englishman and no forgiveness toward the cowboys from the women at the whorehouse.

The core of the movie is about Will’s inner conflict and lack of forgiveness for himself and his journey to try to rectify that along the way.  We see that he tries to show compassion to the cowboy he shot but allowing him water.  He tried to cope with alcohol as soon as he learns of Ned’s death and feels guilt.  Ultimately the story ends in a Homer-like rage, as it’s clear that Will hasn’t forgiven himself for his past as much as his goodness would compel him to do so.

Answer (score -1):

Unforgiven seems to have a lot of unforgiving, but the whole story is based around the decision of the girls, especially the leader, not forgiving the cowboys (knife slasher and his companion).

If they had taken the horse, or negotiated for a bit more, then the town's whole law enforcement would have all have survived and not been shot dead, directly reflecting back to the prostitutes' bounty.

One comment on other posts:

Bill doesn't like English Bob - not necessarily connected to forgiving - He doesn't like English Bob for his very bad treatment of Chinese people, including shooting them for no reason, apparently.  Also, he doesn't like English Bob because he knows Bob's there to assassinate someone, murder in his eyes.